# How to allow communication between private instances in GCE

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, firewall, google-vpc, private-network

Here is the use case:

- External IPs are not allowed
- Custom VPC exist for the GCP Project
- Instance A has an application running
- Instance B is considered as a client
- SQL Instance C is on VPC too and has only internal IP

The goal is to let B send HTTP requests to A so that A send queries to the SQL Instance C.

What are the networking steps to be done in that case? ( only firewall issue since all instances are on the same network? and if so, what are the rules of firewall to be allowed? )

and WHY we can't ping other servers in GCP if they are on the same VPC?

Thank you

**VPS firewall settings:**

```
[
{
  "allowed": [
    {
      "IPProtocol": "tcp",
      "ports": [
        "22"
      ]
    },
    {
      "IPProtocol": "tcp",
      "ports": [
        "3389"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "description": "Allow incoming traffic on IAP",
  "direction": "INGRESS",
  "disabled": false,
  "kind": "compute#firewall",
  "logConfig": {
    "enable": false
  },
  "name": "fw-allow-iap",
  "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects//global/networks/NETWORK_HERE",
  "priority": 1000,
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects//global/firewalls/fw-allow-iap",
  "sourceRanges": [
    "35.235.240.0/20"
  ]
},
{
  "allowed": [
    {
      "IPProtocol": "tcp",
      "ports": [
        "80"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "description": "",
  "direction": "INGRESS",
  "disabled": false,
  "kind": "compute#firewall",
  "logConfig": {
    "enable": false
  },
  "name": "NETWORK_HERE-allow-http",
  "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects//global/networks/NETWORK_HERE",
  "priority": 1000,
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects//global/firewalls/NETWORK_HERE-allow-http",
  "sourceRanges": [
    "0.0.0.0/0"
  ],
  "targetTags": [
    "http-server"
  ]
},
{
  "allowed": [
    {
      "IPProtocol": "tcp",
      "ports": [
        "443"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "direction": "INGRESS",
  "disabled": false,
  "kind": "compute#firewall",
  "logConfig": {
    "enable": false
  },
  "name": "NETWORK_HERE-allow-https",
  "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects//global/networks/NETWORK_HERE",
  "priority": 1000,
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects//global/firewalls/NETWORK_HERE-allow-https",
  "sourceRanges": [
    "0.0.0.0/0"
  ],
  "targetTags": [
    "https-server"
  ]
}
]
```

**Instance B settings: (Instance A has the same settings as well)**

```
{
"canIpForward": false,
"confidentialInstanceConfig": {
  "enableConfidentialCompute": false
},
"cpuPlatform": "Intel Haswell",
"deletionProtection": false,
"description": "",
"disks": [
  {
    "autoDelete": true,
    "boot": true,
    "deviceName": "instance-1",
    "diskSizeGb": "10",
    "guestOsFeatures": [
      {
        "type": "UEFI_COMPATIBLE"
      },
      {
        "type": "VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE"
      }
    ],
    "index": 0,
    "interface": "SCSI",
    "kind": "compute#attachedDisk",
    "licenses": [
      "projects/debian-cloud/global/licenses/debian-10-buster"
    ],
    "mode": "READ_WRITE",
    "source": "projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/europe-west1-b/disks/instance-1",
    "type": "PERSISTENT"
  }
],
"displayDevice": {
  "enableDisplay": false
},
"kind": "compute#instance",
"machineType": "projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/europe-west1-b/machineTypes/e2-micro",
"metadata": {
  "fingerprint": "S0UuYvDZ4Tg=",
  "kind": "compute#metadata"
},
"name": "instance-1",
"networkInterfaces": [
  {
    "kind": "compute#networkInterface",
    "name": "nic0",
    "network": "projects/PROJECT_ID/global/networks/NETWORK_HERE",
    "networkIP": "10.0.1.4",
    "subnetwork": "projects/PROJECT_ID/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/SUBNET_HERE"
  }
],
"reservationAffinity": {
  "consumeReservationType": "ANY_RESERVATION"
},
"scheduling": {
  "automaticRestart": true,
  "onHostMaintenance": "MIGRATE",
  "preemptible": false
},
"selfLink": "projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/europe-west1-b/instances/instance-1",
"serviceAccounts": [
  {
    "email": "PROJECT_ID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
    ]
  }
],
"shieldedInstanceConfig": {
  "enableIntegrityMonitoring": true,
  "enableSecureBoot": false,
  "enableVtpm": true
},
"shieldedInstanceIntegrityPolicy": {
  "updateAutoLearnPolicy": true
},
"startRestricted": false,
"status": "RUNNING",
"tags": {
  "items": [
    "http-server",
    "https-server"
  ]
},
"zone": "projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/europe-west1-b"
```

}

Comment: VPC Firewall rules control VPC traffic. By default, two machines in the same VPC can ping each other provided the OS internal firewall permits this. Edit your question with details. Your question is too vague on the configuration details.

Comment: @JohnHanley all machines are on the VPC, isn't that sufficient to know?
tried to ping machine A from B but didn't work.. i think there should be a firewall rule for that ?

Comment: Please read this section of this link: `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.` https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Search engines have challenges reading images. I cannot even read your images.

Comment: Regarding ping: I do not see a rule allowing ICMP traffic. By default, a VPC is created with this rule (`default-allow-icmp`). Someone has deleted it. Create a rule allowing ICMP within your VPC. Next, figure out if you have an internal OS firewall and if that allows ICMP. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

Comment: This has solved the issue.. don't hesitate to post your comment as an answer so I would accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From John Hanley's [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67803303/how-to-allow-communication-between-private-instances-in-gce#:%7E:text=Regarding%20ping%3A%20I,vpc/docs/firewalls)

> By default, a VPC is created with this rule (default-allow-icmp). Someone has deleted it. Create a rule allowing ICMP within your VPC. Next, figure out if you have an internal OS firewall and if that allows ICMP. Refer gcp documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)